# Sending HashMap to Backend in MultiPart request using retrofit

Tags: android, http, retrofit, retrofit2, multipart

I'm trying to make a PUTrequest using retrofit. All parameters sent except the data inside the Classic Java object. it contains a and other data but the backend not adding any of its parameters. I tried adding the HashMap as an individual part "working_session_pauses_attributes" but also not sent. Any solution or suggestion?

Thanks in advance

```
 @Multipart
@PUT(WORKING_SESSION_PATH)
Observable<Response<WorkingSession>> updateWorkingSession(@Path(LOCATION_ID_VARIABLE) String locationId,
                                                          @Path(EMPLOYEE_ID_VARIABLE) String employeeId,
                                                          @Path(WORKING_SESSION_ID_VARIABLE) String workingSessionId,
                                                          @Part("working_session_id") String working_session_id,
                                                          @Part("ends_at") String ends_at,
                                                          @Part("starts_at") String starts_at,
                                                          @Part("secure_id") String secure_id,
                                                          @Part ("tag_ids[]") Long[] tag_ids,
                                                          @Part ("working_session_pauses_attributes") HashMap<Integer, UpdateBreakDataModel> working_session_pauses_attributes,
                                                          @Part ("data") CreateWorkingSessionRequestBody CreateWorkingSessionRequestBody,
                                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part end_signature,
                                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part start_signature_break,
                                                          @Part MultipartBody.Part end_signature_break);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you doing, you want post request but you are using put, please check. I am showing you my code how i am sending data using Hash map.

This is my method declaration:

```
@GET(ApiConstant.REQUEST_FORM_CHECK_OUT_ID)
    Call<CheckOutIdResponseParent> callRequestFormCheckoutId(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params);
```

& here i am calling that method using hashmap.

```
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("category_id", categoryId);
            params.put("currency", currency);
            params.put("language", language);

      ServiceApi mRetrofitCommonService = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
            Call<ProductListParentResponse> call = mRetrofitCommonService.callProductListApi(params);
```

Comment: Sorry it's a PUT not POST. And what I need is to send this request which needed to contain a file and so I need to use Multi Part. All data is sent properly except the HashMap. The hashmap is a part of the parameters not a hashmap for parameters itself. That's the issue exactly.